# Input only reading one integer in a small simple program

Tags: java

So I just started studying Java a few weeks ago and came across a program exercise where I have to basically ask a user to input a word, then input 4 numbers, though those numbers can't be larger than the word length.

Now to the question, my code probably looks bad and doesn't make sense if so please tell me what is wrong since I have little knowledge so far, but can someone tell me how to make use of a single scanner to read 4 numbers and return the letter corresponding to that number with charAt?

I'm thankful for any advice given.

This is what I have, it only outputs 1 letter.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringFun {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
        String userWord = input.next(); //Use next to read only one word
        int length = userWord.length();

        System.out.print("Enter four indices: ");
        int userNumbers = input.nextInt();

        if (userNumbers <= length - 1) {
            char randomWord = userWord.charAt(userNumbers);
            System.out.println(randomWord);
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("All indices must be less than your word.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a [for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: Before the message containing "Enter four indices" add `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {...}` or a `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks both of you, still figuring it out, since I haven't covered "for" or "while" in the lectures only "if" and "else."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after `System.out.print("Enter four indices: ");` you can try something like:

```
int correct = 0;
while(correct < 4) {
    int userNumbers = input.nextInt();
    if (userNumbers < length) {
        char randomWord = userWord.charAt(userNumbers);
        System.out.println(randomWord);
        correct++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("All indices must be less than your word.");
    }
}
```